# How to upload image to Firebase Storage and automatically store it in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently stuck at where I'm trying to upload image to `Firestore Storage` and automatically store the image `URL` to `Cloud Firestore`. I have tried to manually upload the image to `Firebase Storage` and pasting the image url to `Cloud Firestore` then retrieving it to show the image in my app and it works. Heres the coding that I have done so far:

`models/enter.dart`

```
class Enter {

  final String enterId;
  final String enter;
  final String price;
  final String url;

  Enter({this.enter, this.price, @required this.enterId, this.url});

  factory Enter.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return Enter(
        enter: json['enter'],
        price: json['price'],
        url: json['url'],
        enterId: json['enterId']
    );
  }

  Map<String,dynamic> toMap(){
    return {
      'enter':enter,
      'price':price,
      'url':url,
      'enterId':enterId
    };
  }
}
```

`services/firestore_service2`

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:journal_app/src/models/enter.dart';

class FirestoreService2 {
  FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  //Get Entries
  Stream<List<Enter>> getEnter(){
    return _db
        .collection('enters')
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
        .map((doc) => Enter.fromJson(doc.data()))
        .toList());
  }

  //Upsert
  Future<void> setEnter(Enter enter){
    var options = SetOptions(merge:true);

    return _db
        .collection('enters')
        .doc(enter.enterId)
        .set(enter.toMap(),options);
  }

  //Delete
  Future<void> removeEnter(String enterId){
    return _db
        .collection('enters')
        .doc(enterId)
        .delete();
  }

}
```

`provider/enter_provider.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:journal_app/src/models/enter.dart';
import 'package:journal_app/src/services/firestore_service2.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

class EnterProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final firestoreService = FirestoreService2();
  String _enter;
  String _price;
  String _enterId;
  String _url;
  var uuid = Uuid();

  //Getters
  String get enter => _enter;
  String get price => _price;
  String get url => _url;
  Stream<List<Enter>> get enters => firestoreService.getEnter();

  //Setters
  set changeEnter(String enter){
    _enter = enter;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set changePrice(String price){
    _price = price;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set changeUrl(String url){
    _url = url;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  //Functions
  loadAll(Enter enter){
    if (enter != null && price != null){
      _enter =enter.enter;
      _price =enter.price;
      _url=enter.url;
      _enterId = enter.enterId;
    } else {
      _enter = null;
      _price = null;
      _url = null;
      _enterId = null;
    }
  }

  saveEnter(){
    if (_enterId == null){
      //Add
      var newEnter = Enter(enter: _enter, price: _price, url: _url, enterId: uuid.v1());
      print(newEnter.enter);
      print(newEnter.price);
      print(newEnter.url);
      firestoreService.setEnter(newEnter);
    } else {
      //Edit
      var updatedEnter = Enter(enter: _enter, price: _price, url: _url, enterId: _enterId);
      firestoreService.setEnter(updatedEnter);
    }
  }

  removeEnter(String enterId){
    firestoreService.removeEnter(enterId);
  }

}
```

`screens/enter.dart` where user insert product name, price and image

```
import 'package:date_format/date_format.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:journal_app/src/models/enter.dart';
import 'package:journal_app/src/providers/enter_provider.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class EnterScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Enter enter;
  final Enter price;
  final Enter category;

  EnterScreen({this.enter, this.price, this.category});

  @override
  _EnterScreenState createState() => _EnterScreenState();
}

class _EnterScreenState extends State<EnterScreen> {

  final enterController = TextEditingController();
  final enterController2 = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    enterController.dispose();
    enterController2.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    final enterProvider = Provider.of<EnterProvider>(context,listen: false);
    if (widget.enter != null){
      //Edit
      enterController.text = widget.enter.enter;
      enterController2.text = widget.enter.price;

      enterProvider.loadAll(widget.enter);
      enterProvider.loadAll(widget.price);
    } else {
      //Add
      enterProvider.loadAll(null);
    }
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final enterProvider = Provider.of<EnterProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Products')),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Product Name', border: InputBorder.none,
              ),
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 25),
              maxLines: 5,
              minLines: 2,
              onChanged: (String value) => enterProvider.changeEnter = value,
              controller: enterController,
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Product Price', border: InputBorder.none,
              ),
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 25),
              maxLines: 5,
              minLines: 2,
              onChanged: (String value) => enterProvider.changePrice = value,
              controller: enterController2,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              child: Text('Save',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20)),
              onPressed: () {
                enterProvider.saveEnter();
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
            (widget.enter != null) ? RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Text('Delete',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20)),
              onPressed: () {
                enterProvider.removeEnter(widget.enter.enterId);
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ): Container(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`screens/product.dart` where this screen show the product name, price and image in listview

```
import 'package:date_format/date_format.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:journal_app/src/models/enter.dart';
import 'package:journal_app/src/providers/enter_provider.dart';
import 'package:journal_app/src/screens/enter.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ProductScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final enterProvider = Provider.of<EnterProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Products'),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<List<Enter>>(
          stream: enterProvider.enters,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    leading: Image.network(
                      snapshot.data[index].url,
                      width: 100,
                      height: 100,
                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                    ),
                    trailing:
                    Icon(Icons.edit, color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
                    title: Text(
                      snapshot.data[index].enter, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      snapshot.data[index].price,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) =>
                              EnterScreen(enter: snapshot.data[index], price: snapshot.data[index])));
                    },
                  );
                });
          }),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context)
              .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EnterScreen()));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The goal is to `upload` image to `Firebase Storage`, storing the `image url` at the same time when `uploading` new image.

I need advice for this project.

Comment: I did this a while before. When you are storing your image file after successfully uploading your image you need to get the image download URL and then you can save your image `URL` to `Cloud Firestore`. thats it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to upload image to Firebase Storage & save it in Cloud Firestore, you need to do the following:

Step 1: Get the image that you want to upload
For this, you can use the [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) package
It will give you a `PickedFile` object (let's say it pickedFile). Convert this object to a `File` object by using this code:

```
final file = File(pickedFile.path);
```

Step 2: Upload this file to Firebase Storage:
Give the image that you want to upload a unique name.

```
final imageName = '${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.png';
```

Create Firebase Storage Reference:

```
final firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child('images/$imageName'); // This will create a images directory in Firebase storage & save your image in that directory
```

Start uploading image:

```
final uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(file);
final taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
```

Get the image URL:

```
final _fileURL = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
```

Save this image URL in Cloud Firestore.

```
// This will save the image in "images" collection & update the "uploadedImage" value of document with id the same as the value of "id" variable. 
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(images).doc(id).update({'uploadedImage': _fileURL});
```

If you are updating an existing object then use the `update` method or else you can use the `set` method.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you must follow bellow steps

1. First upload your image to `Firebase Storage` and get the download `URL`
2. Now you have the download `URL` and you can Upload your `Enter` object to `Cloud FireStore` with the `url`

Bellow method shows how could you store the image and get the download url list

```
Future<String> uploadImage(var imageFile ) async {
    StorageReference ref = storage.ref().child("/photo.jpg");
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(imageFile);
    var dowurl = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
    url = dowurl.toString();
    return url; 
}
```