# How to save an image to firebase storage and cloud firestore at the same time in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I'm really confused how to save an image to Firebase Storage, but also Cloud Firestore. All tutorial in youtube is very confusing because they start on pre-build project with no further explanation, especially when they talk about `imageUrl` to save the picture from Firebase Storage to cloud Firestore.

Here is my **add_new_collection.dart**

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:project_ukk/constants/color_constant.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:project_ukk/models/button_widget.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class AddNewCollection extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddNewCollection({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AddNewCollection> createState() => _AddNewCollectionState();
}

class _AddNewCollectionState extends State<AddNewCollection> {
  File? _image;
  final _picker = ImagePicker();
  //Editing Controllers
  final collectionNameController = TextEditingController();

  Future getImageFromGallery() async {
    final pickedFile = await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    final File image = File(pickedFile!.path);
    setState(() {
      _image = image;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final fileName =
        _image != null ? basename(_image!.path) : 'No File Selected';

    final addNewCollection = Material(
      elevation: 5,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: 60,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
          color: kGreenColor,
        ),
        child: Material(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: Center(
            child: MaterialButton(
              child: Text(
                "Add New Collection",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: GoogleFonts.dongle(
                  fontSize: 28,
                  color: kWhiteColor,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 20, 15),
              minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              onPressed: () {
                // Adding the name of the collection and the image to the Firebase storage and firestore,
                // then navigating to the collection_page.dart,
                // and also displaying the result on colletion_page.dart
                // with the shape of a card from card_collection.dart
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            "New Collection",
            style: GoogleFonts.dongle(
              fontSize: 40,
              color: kVeryDarkCyan,
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: kWhiteColor,
          elevation: 0,
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back,
              color: kVeryDarkCyan,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              //passing this to our root
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ),
        body: Form(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Center(
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 25,
                        ),
                        color: kPowderBlue,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            ButtonWidget(
                              icon: Icons.attach_file,
                              text: 'Select Picture',
                              onPressed: () {
                                getImageFromGallery();
                              },
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 5),
                            Text(
                              fileName,
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 30),
                            Text(
                              'Collection Name',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                            TextField(
                              autofocus: false,
                              controller: collectionNameController,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                contentPadding:
                                    EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
                                hintText: "Example: My Hotwheels",
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 20,
                            ),
                            addNewCollection,
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This the **button_widget.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final IconData icon;
  final String text;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  const ButtonWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.icon,
    required this.text,
    required this.onPressed,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ElevatedButton(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 29, 136, 194),
          minimumSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
        ),
        child: buildContent(),
        onPressed: onPressed,
      );

  Widget buildContent() => Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Icon(icon, size: 28),
          SizedBox(width: 16),
          Text(
            text,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ],
      );
}
```

for the `onPressed` at **add_new_collection.dart** in the `final addNewCollection` is the button where the magic happen, but I don't have the magic that I need. So, please help

**Side Note:** if you also have a way to fetch the data from the Firestore and displaying it on to the screen, please pass me some of your way, Thank you.

Comment: Hi, have you went through this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66684906/15774177), the community member has explained step by step process to store the image in Firebase storage as well as cloud Firestore.

Comment: @ZeenathSN I don't know that there already a question like mine, thank you for letting me know